# Rotate center not working for :before and :after elements

Tags: html, css, button

Whenever the top and bottom bars rotate, it isn't centered on the middle. How can I fix this?
I want the 3 bars to form an X shape from the hamburger shape, but when the animation starts, the bottom and top bars get offset from the center when they rotate.

What I have currently:

```js
function toggleState(target) {
  target.classList.toggle("animate");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --btn-size: min(8vh, 8vw);
  --bar-height: calc(var(--btn-size) / 5);
  --margin-top: calc(var(--bar-height)*2);
  --margin-bottom: calc(var(--bar-height)*-2);
  --animation: 1s;
  --anim-half: calc(var(--animation)/2);
  --anim-func: ease-in-out;
  --btn-color: #929292;
}

body {
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 5%;
}

#menu-btn {
  height: var(--btn-size);
  width: var(--btn-size);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-icon,
#menu-icon::before,
#menu-icon::after {
  height: var(--bar-height);
  width: var(--btn-size);
  background-color: var(--btn-color);
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#menu-icon {
  transition: rotate var(--animation) var(--anim-func) 0.00s;
}

#menu-icon::before {
  transition: translate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) var(--anim-half), rotate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) 0.00s;
  content: "";
  transform: translateY(var(--margin-top));
}

#menu-icon::after {
  transition: translate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) var(--anim-half), rotate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) 0.00s;
  content: "";
  transform: translateY(var(--margin-bottom));
}

.animate #menu-icon {
  transition: rotate var(--animation) var(--anim-func) 0.00s;
  rotate: 360deg;
}

.animate #menu-icon::before {
  transition: translate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) 0.00s, rotate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) var(--anim-half);
  translate: 0px var(--margin-bottom);
  rotate: 45deg;
}

.animate #menu-icon::after {
  transition: translate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) 0.00s, rotate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) var(--anim-half);
  translate: 0px var(--margin-top);
  rotate: -45deg;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="menu-btn" onclick="toggleState(this)">
    <div id="menu-icon" class=""></div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

I tried transform-origin: center on every line but it didn't work. I expected it to rotate centered about the middle of the original.

Comment: This to me does differ from what users would expect from a click on that icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a slightly different idea and simplify your code like below:

```js
function toggleState(target) {
  target.classList.toggle("animate");
}
```

```css
:root {
  --btn-size: 20vmin; /* no need to use min between vh and vw, vmin will do it for you */
  --animation: 1s;
  --anim-half: calc(var(--animation)/2);
  --anim-func: ease-in-out;
  --btn-color: #929292;
}

#menu-btn {
  height: var(--btn-size);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: /* the background will create the middle bar */
   linear-gradient(var(--btn-color) 0 0) 
   50%/100% 20% no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  transition: 
    rotate var(--animation) var(--anim-func),
    background-size 0s var(--anim-half);
}
#menu-btn::before,
#menu-btn::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset-inline: 0;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: var(--btn-color);
  transition: 
    translate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) var(--anim-half), 
    rotate    var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func);
}
#menu-btn::before { top: 0}
#menu-btn::after { bottom: 0}

#menu-btn.animate{
  rotate: 360deg;
  background-size: 0% 20%;
}
#menu-btn.animate::before,
#menu-btn.animate::after {
  transition: 
    translate var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func), 
    rotate    var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) var(--anim-half);
}
#menu-btn.animate::before {
  rotate: 45deg;
  translate: 0 calc(2*var(--btn-size)/5);
}
#menu-btn.animate::after {
  rotate: -45deg;
  translate: 0 calc(-2*var(--btn-size)/5);
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id="menu-btn" onclick="toggleState(this)"></button>
```

Comment: Nice rotation effect!  No surprise given the author :)  Good job Temani!

Comment: It's beautiful, thank you. Amazing to see my idea become a reality. Time to remove one line at a time to see how it all works, lol.

Comment: vmin is my new best friend.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to rotate the #menu-icon block inside of which there are &:before and &:after pseudo-elements. I'd suggest you use the following structure:

```
<div id="menu-icon" class="">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

```js
 function toggleState(target) {
                target.classList.toggle("animate");
            }
```

```css
:root {
    --btn-size: min(8vh, 8vw);
    --bar-height: calc(var(--btn-size) / 5);
    --margin-top: calc(var(--bar-height)*2);
    --margin-bottom: calc(var(--bar-height)*-2);
    --animation: 1s;
    --anim-half: calc(var(--animation)/2);
    --anim-func: ease-in-out;
    --btn-color: #929292;
}
body {
    height: max-content;
    width: max-content;
    margin: 5%;
}

#menu-btn {
    height: var(--btn-size);
    width: var(--btn-size);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-icon {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

#menu-icon span {
    height: var(--bar-height);
    width: var(--btn-size);
    background-color: var(--btn-color);
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    top: calc( 50% - var(--bar-height) / 2);
    transform-origin: center center;
    transition:all var(--anim-half) var(--anim-func) var(--anim-half);
}

#menu-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  
    margin-top: var(--margin-bottom);
}

#menu-icon span:nth-child(2) {
 
}

#menu-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  
    margin-top: var(--margin-top);
}

.animate #menu-icon span:nth-child(1) {
    
    margin-top: 0;
    rotate: -45deg;
}

.animate #menu-icon span:nth-child(2) {
    width:0;
  
    rotate: 360deg;
}

.animate #menu-icon span:nth-child(3) {
    
    margin-top:0;
    rotate: 45deg;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script>
            function toggleState(target) {
                target.classList.toggle("animate");
            }
        </script>
  </head>
   <body>
        <div id = "menu-btn" onclick = "toggleState(this)">
            <div id = "menu-icon" class = "">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in the CSS, target the individual spans using span:nth-child(1), span:nth-child(2), and so on. This way, the #menu-icon itself isn't part of the animation and there won't be any unexpected rotations. To fix the offset during rotation, you can utilize the transform: translate property.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm using before and after so that when I rotate the center bar it rotates the other 2 bars around it. Then, they move in and rotate 45 degrees while also being turned in a circle. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This has actually helped me with something completely unrelated, so thanks lol